# replace empty space with dash only if trailing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using regEx and replace method to replace an empty space with a dash but I only want this to happen if there is a following character. For example
if the input field looked like this then replace empty space between temp and string with dash

```
input = "temp string";
```

if it looked like this then it would just remove the empty space

```
input = "temp  ";
```

here is my regEx replace right now. But not sure how to check if there are trailing characters.

```
input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
```

Comment: [`String.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Comment: @RobW: [`jQuery.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duNqR/)

```
input = $.trim(input.replace(/\b \b/g, '-'));
```

[**`\b` (word boundaries) info**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

[**`jQuery.trim()` api**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Comment: Your answer looks a lot better without the loudness.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:
the first replace takes care of the trailing spaces (if there's  at least one)
the second one performs your original replacement

```
str.replace(/\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s+/g, '-');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zd78k/)

Answer (score 0):

`/\s+$/` only finds trailing spaces, so add `.replace(/\s+$/, '')` after `.value`

Comment: I added this to the end of my above code and it still just adds the dash